How to make transform view for the nested structure data?
How can I map nested structure data with std::views::transform?
In the code below the transformation for as_v1 works just fine and allows copying the data.
How can I do the same for the data in the nested structure NS?
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    float v1;
    float v2;

    struct SN {
        float v3;
    };

    SN sn;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> aos{ { 1.0f, 2.0f, { 3.0f } } };
    std::vector<float> soa(aos.size());

    // Would work just fine for the:
    // auto as_v1 = aos | std::views::transform(&S::v1);

    // How could I manage a nested structure's member:
    // This, of course, doesn't compile because of types inconsistency
    auto as_v3 = aos | std::views::transform(offsetof(S, sn.v3));

    std::ranges::copy(as_v3, soa.begin());
    std::cout << "soa value:" << soa[0] << std::endl;
}

I understand that S::SN::v3 won't work since we need the offset of the member and it will be relative to the sn object and it seems that offsetof should do the job, but I can't figure out how to make type conversion.
Is is doable?
Demo

You are trying to access the member of a member.
This will do it.
auto as_v3 = aos | std::views::transform(&S::sn) | std::views::transform(&S::SN::v3);


You can use regular lambda:
auto as_v3 = aos | std::views::transform([](const S& s){ return s.sn.v3;});

Demo

It looks like the lambda should return the reference to avoid copy.

For float vs const float&, I prefer copy, but in general case const reference is indeed better.

@Jarod42, thank you for the solution. On the float vs const float&, I would prefer float& since in this case this transform could be used both ways to copy from the field and to the field in the way std::ranges::copy(soa.as_v3.begin());. (On the answer itself, I like your one as flexible and generic, but this time will accept Drew's as more specific for this particular case; hope you would agree).

Lambda is indeed error prone when return type should be reference (with missing trailing return type). [](auto&& s) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(s)>(s).sn.v3; } would handle it, but no longer a clear syntax IMO.
